# Heroku npm ERR! app@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --prod --aot`

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

Im trying to push my angular+nodeJS application to heroku but I cant get it to deploy. I've tried ALOOOOOOT of things and combinations.

This is the error message:

```
remote:        > app@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f
remote:        > ng build --prod --aot
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:76
remote:        throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent `
remote:        ^
remote:
remote:        InvalidConfigError: Parsing '/tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f/.angular-cli.json' failed. Ensure the file is valid JSON.
remote:        Error: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 493
remote:        at Function.fromConfigPath (/tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:76:19)
remote:        at Function.fromProject (/tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:88:46)
remote:        at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_cef68857f715f26620e2e4f29fab803f/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:7:35)
remote:        at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
remote:        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
remote:        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
remote:        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
remote:        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
remote:        at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
remote:        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! app@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --prod --aot`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-11-13T20_41_32_365Z-debug.log
```

And this is the package.json file. I moved everything for angular away from devDependencies just to try to see if it could fix the error but it didnt help.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.4",
    "npm": "5.2.0"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "watch-build": "ng build --watch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-split": "^0.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "granim": "^1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on what that trigger this error and how to fix it?

Br

Comment: Does your repository include `.angular-cli.json` file?

Comment: Yes, I see. There is comments there //, thinks them that messes this up. Will try to build later. Thanks!

Comment: Probably that's the reason ;)